# Google Chrome Расширения. Из страницы на страницу передать данные?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Делаю небольшое расширение, встрял на проблеме.
Допустим есть сайт `http://site.ru`
После авторизации я попадаю на `http://site.ru/home.php`
Так же есть страница `http://site.ru/timer.php` , на этой странице отсчет времени.

На `http://site.ru/timer.php` я через jquery получаю данные `$('#timer').text();` и хочу их передать на `http://site.ru/home.php`

Как можно передать данные с `http://site.ru/timer.php` на `http://site.ru/home.php` ??

Сайт чужой, так что...

Answer (score 0):

1. Можно попробовать средствами чистого js или jQuery записать данные в local storage хрома.
2. Лучше воспользоваться готовым апи хрома - https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Могли бы вы пояснить как правильно это использовать? Каким то образом надо прописать, что для такой то страницы используется такой скрипт с содержимом chrome.storage.sync.set({key: value}, function() {
          console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
        });   а на главной странице подключается скрипт с содержимым  chrome.storage.sync.get(['key'], function(result) {
          console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
        });  или я все не правильно понял =\

Answer (score 0):

Вам отлично подходит [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). Так как этот API поддерживает метод для отслеживания событий изменения хранилища, то на "принимающей стороны" отследить, когда были положены данные. Все решается использованием одного и того же для `content-script` для обеих страниц. 
Пример:

**content-script.js**

```js
// Прослушивание события изменения
if(document.location.href.includes('site.ru/home.php')) {
    chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
        if(namespace === 'local') {
            // пришли новые данные, можно использовать
            console.log(changes.data.newValue);
        }
    });

}


// Передающая сторона
if(document.location.href.includes('site.ru/timer.php')) {
    const el = document.querySelector('#data');
    const txt = el.innerText;

    // Записываем данные
    chrome.storage.local.set({
        data: txt
    });
}
```